# How can I catch a memory leak from a ksh script?

Tags: memory, ksh

Let's suppose that I have a script like, exploit.sh :

```
#!/bin/ksh
while true ; do
    ...
    ...
 done
```

and in this loop there are some commands that occur memory leakage. How can I see/debug that?

Comment: First you'll have to explain how you managed to get `ksh` to leak memory.  Shells are not supposed to leak.  They may spawn memory-intensive processes which fail to exit, but those are not leaks in the strictest sense of the term.

Comment: Yes, but both bash and ksh are in C, so I suppose that they spawn a memory-intensive process that can cause leaks (without the strictest sense of the term).

e.g. 
  `valgrind --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes ./exploit.sh`

Comment: That will debug the `ksh` process, and (I think) the processes it invokes, for memory leaks.  It will not warn you if (for instance) `ksh` is spawning a lot of processes that never exit.  To keep track of spawned processes, you may find [these commands](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67668/elegantly-get-list-of-descendant-processes) helpful.